# If Melatonin is anti-gonadal, why is it associated with early sexual maturity in congenitally blind girls?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry

If melatonin is anti-gonadal, that is, it delays sexual maturity, then shouldn’t it delay sexual maturity in congenitally blind girls rather than helping them attain sexual maturity at an early age?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on **this** site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, we expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). For example please provide evidence for your statements that melatonin is: 1) "anti-gonadal" — also under what conditions this is true and what sort of delays occur? 2) "associated with early sexual maturity" — also how early? Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

melatonin released from pineal gland and and its one of the function is that it delays sexual maturity. but there are also a point to remember that pineal gland is activated at that time when light stimulate the retina but in the case of blind person activation of pineal gland is not occurs. that's why hr. like melatonin is not secreted and sexual maturity come before time. it come 2-4 years before the normal age.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We expect all answers to contain references so that readers interested in knowing more may look them up. Please add some references to your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: i read this from books so you may find this at : 1. ncert - biology - xii   or 2. allen module-8 chapter 2

Comment: Isn’t melatonin secreted during the scotopic phase? That would mean that in blind girls melatonin levels should be higher compared to serotonin (secreted during daytime). Therefore, blind girls should have a delayed sexual maturity rather than early sexual maturity.